# Spring Boot Actuator custom value in metric result

Tags: spring-boot-actuator

As using Spring Boot Actuator stater, we can fetch the metric of application
using just hitting metrics endpoint

I have go throw with some metrics api, and found it support **CounterService** ( A service that can be used to increment, decrement and reset a named counter value.) and another **GaugeService**(service that can be used to submit a named double value for storage and analysis)

I need to add a custom field in metric result, basically i am batching some process and then need to count all the batching processed and show in metric,

I can achieve it using GaugeService but I can't use GaugeService as it's took double value, and i don't want it show count in double format
 eg.

```
gauge.c.s.count=1.0
```

also problem with CounterService is, it have a method name increment (which increment value with 1 in every call)so problem here if 
i need to add 500 counts then i need 500 iterations in CounterService, :( so can't use it.

Know how can i create my own custom metrics service like CounterService or GaugeService, my custom result show with in metrics result (just hitting /metrics url)

(Note : i don't want to persist count in db also don't want to expose this count using any another endpoints, main task is showing this total count in metric result)